# LightsOut game solving method "reduced echolean ".Does it always gives correct result?

Tags: algorithm, gaussian

I am studing the algorithm given [here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=lights-out), and 
somewhere it is claimed that it is efficent and always give correct result.

But, I try to run the algorithm and it is not giving me correct or efficent output for the following patterns.
For 5 x 5 grid, where (n) is light number and 0/1 state whethere the light is on/off, 1 ON and 0 OFF.

```
(1)1    (2)0    (3)0    (4)0    (5)0      the output should be 1,7,13,19,25(Pressing this light will make the full grid OFF. But what I am getting is this  
(6)0    (7)1    (8)0    (9)0    (10)0     3,5,6,7,8,10,13,16,18,19,20,21,23. 
(11)0   (12)0   (13)1   (14)0   (15)0      
(16)0   (17)0   (18)0   (19)1   (20)0
(21)0   (22)0   (23)0   (24)0   (25)1
```

While for some pattern it is giving me correct output as below.

```
    (1)0    (2)0    (3)0    (4)0    (5)1      the output should be 5,9,13,17,21, and the algorithm is giving me correct result. 
    (6)0    (7)0    (8)0    (9)1    (10)0      
    (11)0   (12)0   (13)1   (14)0   (15)0      
    (16)0   (17)1   (18)0   (19)0   (20)0
    (21)1   (22)0   (23)0   (24)0   (25)0
```

If somebody need a code let me know I can post it.

Can please somebody let me know if this methods will always give correct as well as efficient result or not ?

Comment: I tried your first 5x5 grid and `3,5,6,7,8,10,13,16,18,19,20,21,23` does turn all the lights off as expected. You're right that it's not as efficient as it can possibly be, but the algorithm doesn't promise to find the smallest solution.

Comment: @Kevin have you run the code given in the link.

Comment: No. I'm just confused because you say that your first example is not correct, but it's giving me the correct result.

Comment: @Kevin I mean to say not efficient. I have written the code given in link in java. So I am thinking may be I have miss something in implementation.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with your implementation. I just think your definition of "efficient" is more strict than the original author's. Maybe he considers "efficient" as "less than 25 button presses".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm the author of the code you linked to.) To the best of my knowledge, the code is correct (and I'm sure that the high-level algorithm of using Gaussian elimination over GF(2) is correct). The solution it produces is guaranteed to solve the puzzle, though it's not necessarily the minimal number of button presses. The "efficiency" I was referring to in the writeup refers to the time complexity of solving the puzzle overall (it can solve a Lights Out grid in polynomial time, as opposed to the exponential-time brute-force solution of trying all possible combinations) rather than to the "efficiency" of the generated solution.

I actually don't know any efficient algorithms for finding a solution requiring the minimum number of button presses. Let me know if you find one!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found one paper [here](http://online.redwoods.edu/instruct/darnold/laproj/Fall2001/Emilia/emilia_paper.pdf) which is very similar to yours one. But, here they have mention there are four solution possible and too choose the best from it. I tried to understand it but having difficult in understanding the NULLSPACE vector(b1,b2)
 ?Like why we need it, how to generate it etc. Let me know if it is clear to you.